# Terminal and iTerm not working after upgrading to macOS Sierra

Tags: terminal

After I updated to macOS Sierra, Terminal.app and iTerm failed with the same error:

```
login: /usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

Now I can fix Terminal with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985304/after-opening-terminal-process-quits-and-cannot-access-terminal-again). But then in Terminal:

```
mkdir: /Users/username/.bash_sessions: Operation not permitted
```

Also, this does not fix iTerm. So where does this `/usr/local/bin/bash` come from, why is it missing, and if Sierra deleted it, why isn't the new Terminal updated?

There's a [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317240/fail-to-open-terminal) with the same problem as mine. So I'm not alone.

Answer (score 3):

- Open System Preferences > Users & Groups.
- Unlock the padlock at the bottom of the preference pane
- Hold down the option key and click your account then click the Advanced Options... menu
- Change your shell to `/bin/bash`
- Click the `OK` button and close the preference pane.
- Logout then log back in

Comment: Thanks, now I know where the default shell for a user is.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local/bin/bash` was from `brew install bash`. I had `/usr/local/bin/bash` in `/etc/shells`. Somehow Sierra update deleted `/usr/local/bin/bash` and both Terminal and iTerm stopped working.
I had to revert back to `/bin/bash`, reinstall `brew` and bash 4.4 from brew, and now all is fine.